# Make a link stay underlined until only other button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this page here that will be a list of partners by categories.

https://www.stirringminds.com/partners/

If you click on the sidebar categories, the link will stay underline, but if you click any place in the page, the link will become inactive.

CSS:

```
button:hover { 
    text-decoration: underline;
    color:#000;
}
button:focus { 
    text-decoration: underline;
    color:#000;
}
button:active { 
    text-decoration: underline;
    color:#000;
}
button:visited { 
    text-decoration: underline;
    color:#000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button id="showall" style="border:none;">All Deals</button>
<button id="show" style="border:none;">Business</button>
<button id="show2" style="border:none;">Design</button>
<button id="show3" style="border:none;">Development</button>
<button id="show4" style="border:none;">Marketing</button>
```

How can the link stay underlined unless I click other buttons in the categories?

Thanks.

Comment: try this link https://jsfiddle.net/kblau237/yeknpg8t/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kblau237/yeknpg8t/1/ is a better link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jquery, you can assign a class on click that adds the underline.

```js
var $buttons = jQuery('button');
$buttons.on('click',function() {
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('active').siblings('button').removeClass('active');
})
```

```css
button:hover, button:focus, button:active, button:visited, .active { 
    text-decoration: underline;
    color:#000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="showall" class="active" style="border:none;">All Deals</button>
<button id="show" style="border:none;">Business</button>
<button id="show2" style="border:none;">Design</button>
<button id="show3" style="border:none;">Development</button>
<button id="show4" style="border:none;">Marketing</button>
```

A pure js version would be something like...

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

function setActive(el) {
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      if (buttons[i] == el) {
        el.classList.toggle("active");
      } else {
        buttons[i].classList.remove('active');
      }
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    setActive(this);
  });
}
```

```css
button:hover, button:focus, button:active, button:visited, .active { 
    text-decoration: underline;
    color:#000;
}
```

```html
<button id="showall" class="active" style="border:none;">All Deals</button>
<button id="show" style="border:none;">Business</button>
<button id="show2" style="border:none;">Design</button>
<button id="show3" style="border:none;">Development</button>
<button id="show4" style="border:none;">Marketing</button>
```

Comment: Heya thanks for the reply, I'm building the site in Wordpress and I notice that some jquery isn't well accepted. It runs on the snippet but not on my site. should I try jQuery.noConflict(); ?

Comment: @RuiFarinha use `jQuery` instead of `$` - updated my answer. that work?

Comment: No, unfortunatelly it didn't :(

Comment: Hey it worked, simple error, I had the script in the header instead of footer... Thanks!

Comment: Can you help me now with making the button "All Deals" be active on page load until other link is clicked?

Comment: @RuiFarinha oh haha great. i just re-wrote it in vanilla js for you. updated my answer. And to make "all deals" active, just add `class="active"`. Updated my answer with that, too.

Comment: Now the All Deals in underline but if I click other link and then some place on the site, the selected link loses the active status and the underline :(

Comment: @RuiFarinha does it happen in my demo?

Comment: No, your snippet is fine

Comment: Wordpress is a real pain in the ass with jquery :/

Comment: I just looked on your site. You added the code twice. You only need either the vanilla js or the jquery. I only wrote the vanilla js because you said you couldn't get jQuery to work... I'd use jquery if you were able to get that to work and just remove the vanilla js

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should can add a class called "sidebarbuttons" to all of your links, and then attach the following onclick event to all buttons with that class:

```
$(".sidebarbuttons").on("click", function() { 
   $(".sidebarbuttons").not(this).each(function() { 
      $(this).css("text-decoration","none");
   });
   $(this).css("text-decoration","underline");
});
```

This will remove the underline from all elements with the class "sidebarbuttons" and then add the underline to only the clicked element.

Comment: Another approach would be to modify the above code to apply or remove a class that specifies the text-decoration state using addClass() or removeClass()

Comment: I'm building the site in Wordpress and it doesn't receive jquery very well, I'm gonna try this but I think I need to change the $ in your code to jQuery?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but yes, in Wordpress you need to change the $ to jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

ONE Link active AT a time Now.  This is how you do it:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index950</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .keepShow {
            text-decoration: underline;
            color: #000;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".ap").click(function (event) {
                $(".ap").removeClass("keepShow");
                $(this).addClass("keepShow");
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button id="showall" class="ap" style="border:none;">All Deals</button>
        <button id="show" class="ap" style="border:none;">Business</button>
        <button id="show2" class="ap" style="border:none;">Design</button>
        <button id="show3" class="ap" style="border:none;">Development</button>
        <button id="show4" class="ap" style="border:none;">Marketing</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I modified-adding line $(".ap").removeClass("keepShow");

Answer (score -1):

Plain old javascript:

```
var catButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".wpb_wrapper button");
catButtons.forEach(function(){
  catButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    //remove all other active classes first
    document.querySelectorAll(".wpb_wrapper button").forEach(function(){
      this.classList.remove("active");
    });
    this.classList.toggle("active"); //add to current
  });
});
```